# Delete a certain object from an ArrayList java

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList on Java to store several orders from a factory. These orders have several attributes, amongst them is `idPedido`.
Thing is, if I declare orders 1, 2 and 3, delete order 2 via a method called `bajaPedido` (Shown below):

```
public void bajaPedido(){
     try{
              idPedido=teclado.nextInt();
              listaPedidos.remove(idPedido); 
           }catch(InputMismatchException e){
               teclado.next();
              System.out.print("Debe utilizar números, por favor, repita el proceso");
           }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
               teclado.next();
               System.out.println("No existe un pedido con ese ID");
            }
    }
```

then the 3rd order will be on the second place of the array, because `idPedido` in this situation refers to the position of the array, not to the variable stored inside the object.

Question is, how could I code it in a way that if I type in the id it will search up which object contains such id and removes it, instead of removing the position the id equals to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Iterator` as shown below:

```
idPedido = teclado.nextInt();
for(Iterator<Order> itr = listaPedidos.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){
    Order order = itr.next();
    if(order.getId() == idPedido){
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

If the `id` of all the orders in `listaPedidos` are unique, use `break;` after `itr.remove();` for a better performance (i.e. to prevent the loop running even after removing the desired order).

Comment: That's an interesting approach too, thanks to you and Jordi now I have a much better insight on how to work with arrays. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are most welcome. This is the recommended way to delete an item from a `List`.

Comment: Just tried, it did work and now i can rework several methods with it. Seriously, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest approch would be to use a Map instead of a list, where the key should be your "idPedido" and value the "pedido object".

```
Map<Integer, Pedido> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(idPedido, Pedido);
map.remove(idPedido);
```

If you want to still use a List, you should remove "Pedido" objects from your "listaPedidos" with this method from list interface in orther to be not bounded to your list index.

```
boolean remove(Object o)
```

In that case you will have to implement "equals" method on your Pedido class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Oh I see, now I understand how maps are used, it makes much more sense than using a list. I'll be probably be working with the second method you proposed, since I lack experience using maps and I'm on a tight schedule.
 Thanks a lot, mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using stream api

```
List<Orders> orders= contain orders object
orders.stream().filter(item -> item.getIdPedido().equals("Your Id")).findFirst()
            .map(p -> {
                orders.remove(p);
                return p;
            }).get();
```

I hope it may work.

Comment: I'm using what Arvind suggested but, nonetheless, many thanks for your response and the hindsight on the stream api, it's a nice tool to have on my belt too!